# How to export abi for C++03 from the code written in C++17

Tags: c++, gcc, abi

We have a library written in C++17. Is there any way we build this library for C++03 ABI (for instance for gcc 4.4 or for modern gcc with std=c++03 on) assuming we fix the headers?

Comment: gcc doesn't break ABI compatibility on a whim. It does it when the alternative is noncompliance with the standard.

Comment: Your question is too broad, try to narrow it down to: 1) we have tried XXX 2) expected to get YYY 3) but got ZZZ instead. Provide any relevant error messages, etc.

Comment: I think the flag for that is `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`. Try it, see if it works.

Comment: Worst case scenario if you really need to is export and import your functions in C